# Python Spynner Filling HTML Fields

Tags: python, spynner

I'm trying to fill some fields on http://www.united.com/web/en-US/apps/booking/flight/searchAward.aspx?SB=1&CS=N.

However, I can't get it to work.

As an example, the "From" field in the "Where and when do you want to fly?" box.

```
import spynner

b = spynner.Browser()
b.show()

b.load('http://www.united.com/web/en-US/apps/booking/flight/searchAward.aspx?SB=1&CS=N')

b.wk_fill('input[name=ctl00$ContentInfo$SearchForm$Airports1$Origin$txtOrigin]', 'LONDON, ENGLAND (LHR - HEATHROW)')

b.browse() # to see what's going on.
```

When I try this, the field isn't filled. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use quotes

```
b.wk_fill('input[name="ctl00$ContentInfo$SearchForm$Airports1$Origin$txtOrigin"]', 'LONDON, ENGLAND (LHR - HEATHROW)')
```

With quotes all works fine.

P.S. Sorry for my bad english.